# Ruby quotes, why am I seeing triple double quotes when I save this CSV to a file?

Tags: ruby, fastercsv

I am using FastCSV.

WHen I do this:

title = "\"" + some_title + "\""

My file looks like:

```
"""some title """, 23, 22
```

I want:

```
"some title", 23,22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that fastercsv is adding the extra quotes to escape the quotes in your input string.
So if you're input string is [Hello, CSV], faster csv would have to enclose it within double quotes so that csv parsing isn't disrupted by the comma. Ditto for double quotes which have significance in CSV.

I'd say try sending string without the quotes, let fastercsv decide when it needs the double quotes OR use single quotes like Jacob suggests.

Comment: This is right. FasterCSV does CSV quoting for you. If you add your own quotes, FasterCSV assumes you want quotes *in* your string, for which CSV rules require quoting your whole string, and doubling any internal quotes. Thus the three that you see.